# Polymorphic parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

Lets say I have two models; `Product` and `Recipe`. They can each belong to a group either `ProductGroup` or `RecipeGroup`. Now the group models are basically the same - they have a name column and a counter cache.

Is is possible to use polymorphism here so the groups are merged to a single `Group` model? I know that normally `:polymorphic => true` are applied to the `belongs_to`-side of the association. But I would like to have it on the `has_many`-side instead which is not possible by default. How would you implement this?

Comment: Won't you want to be able to find product groups and recipe groups? With just a Group model that's not easy. Perhaps you want STI rather than poly?